# How do I properly

Tags: c, if-statement, user-input

i'm new to C programming and I have an assignment coming up which I was struggling to work on. My question is that I want to ask the user to Enter in an International Standard Book Number (ISBN) but IF the number does not satisty 9780306406157 then it is an invalid ISBN number. I tried my code but for some odd reason anytime if the user enters 9780306406157 it gives me an Invalid ISBN number which is wrong... Here is my code,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int isbn;

    printf("Enter 13 digits of ISBN-13: ", isbn);
    scanf("%1d", &isbn);

    int isbn_13 = 9780306406157;

    if (isbn == isbn_13) 
    {
        printf("Valid ISBN number.");
    }

    else if (isbn != isbn_13) 
    {
        printf("Invalid ISBN number. ");
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: A 32-bit `int` can store all 9-digit and some 10-digit numbers, but no 13-digit numbers.  Use `long long` for the type and appropriate changes in the format strings.  You would have spotted that something was wrong if you printed the value you entered, and the value you compared it with.

Comment: Also note that the original 10-digit ISBN values could include X as a check digit.

Comment: Why do you have a *field-width* of `1` in `"%1d"` -- that will only read a single-digit no matter how many you enter... If you mean it to be a `long`, that requires a lower-case `'L'` not `'1'`.

Answer (score 1):

So the number you want is 9,780,306,406,157, but the maximum value of an integer is (likely, but implementation specific) 2,147,483,647.

Replace `int` with `unsigned long long` and it should work.

Also replace `scanf("%1d", &isbn);` with `scanf("%llu", &isbn);`